# How to handle function overloads with optional generic parameters?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write an hook that works like this:

```js
const username = useQueryString("username"); // username is of type string
const userId = useQueryString("id", parseInt); // userId is of type number
```

But am having some troubles making the hook function generics work. Here my latest attemp:

```
function useQueryString(
  paramName: string,
  transformer?: undefined
): (string | string[]) | null;

function useQueryString<T>(
  paramName: string,
  transformer?: (value: string | string[]) => T
): T | null {
  // ...
}
```

With the first overload I am trying to say "when `transformer` is undefined, the return value should be string, string[] or undefined", but the I must be doing something wrong.

---

Full code below:

```
export function useQueryString(
  paramName: string,
  transformer?: undefined
): (string | string[]) | null;

export function useQueryString<T = string>(
  paramName: string,
  transformer?: (value: string | string[]) => T
): T | null {
  const search = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.location.search : "";
  const parsed = useMemo(() => queryString.parse(search), [search]);
  const value = parsed[paramName];

  if (value) {
    if (transformer) {
      try {
        return transformer(value);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error transforming ${paramName} that has value ${value}`);
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      return value; //  Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'T | null'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T | null' (ts2322)

    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention:

1. The implementation is not part of the overload list, so currently you've defined only one overload
2. The implementation should handle all overloads, meaning all possible inputs and outputs

---

```
export function useQueryString(
    paramName: string,
): string | string[] | null;

export function useQueryString<T>(
    paramName: string,
    transformer: (value: string | string[]) => T
): T | null;

export function useQueryString<T>(
    paramName: string,
    transformer?: (value: string | string[]) => T
): string | string[] | T | null {
    // ... implementation
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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)